# php - How do I add div in a php function?

Tags: php

I am trying to add a `<div>` to my php, but everything I've found on google hasn't worked for me. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas on how to add a `<div>` in a php function for styling purposes only?

```
<?php
 //get_additional is a custom function
ob_start();
echo get_additional('Cosmos','Trades');
echo nl2br("\n");
 //I want the div to start here
$buffered = ob_get_clean();
echo $buffered;
$times = $buffered;
$imgurl = 'Images/cat.png';

for($i=0;$i<$times;$i++){
echo '<img src="'.$imgurl.'" />';
}
?>
```

Comment: Is it really that easy? everything else I've found have been way more complicated. I'll try it and update.

ETA: I can't believe it was that simple - it was complicated because I had never done it before and couldn't find anything in google even kindof as simple. Thank you guys so much!

Comment: @Anna simple rule of thumb:  HTML is really just text that browsers render if it is formatted correctly.   If there's any text at all that needs to be output, you just need to echo it inside quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `echo` it.

Like you've already used once in your code, `echo '<img src="'.$imgurl.'" />';`

Now coming back to your code:

```
<?php
 //get_additional is a custom function
ob_start();
echo get_additional('Cosmos','Trades');
echo nl2br("\n");
 //I want the div to start here

echo '<div class = "blah">
 // whatever you want to do here

</div>';

$buffered = ob_get_clean();
echo $buffered;
$imgurl = 'Images/cat.png';

for($i=0;$i<$times;$i++){
echo '<img src="'.$imgurl.'" />';
}
?>
```

Comment: A sudden downvote and I skipped my heartbeat, but its alright, its gone.